# Random Access of file

Tags: java

Input = Line number.

Output = Replace the line at given line number by new line.

example =

**a.txt**

```
aaaa
bbbb
cccc
```

input= line number=3 replace with dddd

output

```
aaaa
bbbb
dddd
```

Comment: Open the file, go to line 2, use backspace to remove ccc and type "ddd", Click save. Simple.

Comment: Looks like homework, tagged as such.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [this tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/rafs.html) and [`java.io.RandomAccessFile`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html)